# default value bind to select box

Tags: angularjs

I have got simple select box which should be set as default to state Active(true) or Blocked (false).

Any ideas how to do it as simple as it is possible ?

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedUser.active" >
      <option value="true">Active</option>
      <option value="false">Blocked</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding

```
<option ng-selected="selectedUser.active"  value="true">Active</option>
 <option ng-selected="!selectedUser.active" value="false">Blocked</option>
```